# FIbonacci Time Complexity for non recursive function

Tags: complexity-theory, fibonacci

Hey guys i need some help for this piece of code, computation had become a problem coz i dont know the exact format in computing this code. any help would do.

```
int fib(int n)
{
    int prev = -1;
int result = 1;
int sum = 0;


for(int i = 0;i <= n;++ i)
{
    sum = result + prev;
    prev = result;
    result = sum;
}

return result;   

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you are asking, maybe you can clarify

The time complexity of this algorithm is O(n). The loop will execute n times until i is greater than n. i starts at zero and increments by 1 every iteration of this loop until n.

I hope this helps

Comment: my professor told me to write a non recursive function for fibonacci and she want me to write the time complexity of this algorithm. I dont have any idea what certain formula i need to use.

Comment: This "certain formula" is just knowing Big O. You can read about it here:  http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/data-structures/big-o-notation/.